# How Can I create a procedure that autogenerates a table and automatically fill it with values

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

```
alter procedure inselt

@MES VARCHAR(30), @IDA INT
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @NRODIA INT
DECLARE @NOMBRE_TABLA VARCHAR (50),@ENTRADA VARCHAR(20),@SOPA VARCHAR(20),@PLATO VARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @PLATOP varchar (50)
DECLARE @PLATOS varchar (20)
SET @PLATOP='PLATOP'
set @PLATOS='PLATOS'
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(1)
SET @A=CHAR(39)
DECLARE @tipo varchar(20)
SET @tipo='tipo'
SET @NOMBRE_TABLA=@MES
declare @entrada1 varchar(20)
set @ENTRADA1='entrada'
declare @sopa1 varchar(20)
set @sopa1='sopa'
declare @plato1 varchar(20)
set @plato1='plato'
declare @nd int
DECLARE @xEntrada VARCHAR(20), @xSopa varchar(20), @xPlato varchar(20)
set @nd=1
IF OBJECT_ID(@NOMBRE_TABLA) IS NULL
BEGIN
EXECUTE ('CREATE TABLE ' + @NOMBRE_TABLA+'
(nrodia integer,entrada varchar(20), sopa varchar(20), plato varchar(20),unique(entrada,sopa,plato))')

while @nd<31
begin
EXECUTE(
    'Select TOP 1' + @xEntrada + '=' +@PlatoP+ 'from' +@Platos+ 'where' +@tipo+ '=' +@A+@entrada1+@A+ 'ORDER BY NEWID()
    Select TOP 1' + @xSopa + '=' +@PlatoP+ 'from' +@Platos+ 'where' +@tipo+ '=' +@A+@sopa1+@A+ 'ORDER BY NEWID()
    Select TOP 1' + @xPlato + '=' +@PlatoP+ 'from' +@Platos+ 'where' +@tipo+ '=' +@A+@plato1+@A+ 'ORDER BY NEWID()
    if (not exists(select 1 FROM'+@NOMBRE_TABLA+ 'WHERE' +@entrada1+ '=' +@xEntrada+ 'AND' +@Sopa1+ '=' +@xSopa+ 'AND'
+@PLATO1+ '=' +@xPlato+ '))' + 'BEGIN INSERT INTO' +@NOMBRE_TABLA+ 'values (' +@nd+ ',' +@xEntrada+ ',' +@xSopa+ ','
+@xPlato+ ')' + 'SET' +@nd+ '=' +@nd+ '+1' + 'END END;')
end
END
END
```

This is my try to:
1)Auto create a table just entering "Exec inselt 'a varchar', 'a int of 4 digits'" 
2)After that the created table must be filled with values from another table
The values come from this table :

```
CREATE TABLE PLATOS(Idplatos integer PRIMARY KEY, Tipo varchar(20), PlatoP varchar(20));
---insert---
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('1','entrada','ceviche');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('2','entrada','arrozleche');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('3','sopa','caldo');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('4','sopa','mote');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('5','plato','lomo');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('6','plato','rusa');
```

, the code without a procedure it's:

```
declare @nd int
set @nd=1
DECLARE @xEntrada VARCHAR(20), @xSopa varchar(20), @xPlato varchar(20)
while @nd<=31
begin
    Select TOP 1 @xEntrada = PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'entrada' oRDER BY NEWID()

    Select TOP 1 @xSopa = PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'sopa'  Order by NewId()
    Select TOP 1 @xPlato = PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'plato' oRDER by NewId()

    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM abril2017 WHERE Entrada = @xEntrada AND Sopa = @xSopa AND Plato = @xPlato))
    BEGIN
        Insert into  abril2017 values (@nd,@xEntrada,@xSopa,@xPlato)
        SET @nd=@nd+1
    END
END;
```

Converting that code to:

```
EXECUTE(
    'Select TOP 1' + @xEntrada + '=' +@PlatoP+ 'from' +@Platos+ 'where' +@tipo+ '=' +@A+@entrada1+@A+ 'ORDER BY NEWID()
    Select TOP 1' + @xSopa + '=' +@PlatoP+ 'from' +@Platos+ 'where' +@tipo+ '=' +@A+@sopa1+@A+ 'ORDER BY NEWID()
    Select TOP 1' + @xPlato + '=' +@PlatoP+ 'from' +@Platos+ 'where' +@tipo+ '=' +@A+@plato1+@A+ 'ORDER BY NEWID()
    if (not exists(select 1 FROM'+@NOMBRE_TABLA+ 'WHERE' +@entrada1+ '=' +@xEntrada+ 'AND' +@Sopa1+ '=' +@xSopa+ 'AND'
+@PLATO1+ '=' +@xPlato+ '))' + 'BEGIN INSERT INTO' +@NOMBRE_TABLA+ 'values (' +@nd+ ',' +@xEntrada+ ',' +@xSopa+ ','
+@xPlato+ ')' + 'SET' +@nd+ '=' +@nd+ '+1' + 'END END;')
```

(the complete try of the code it's the first one)
How Can I make this possible? Right now I'm only able to autogenerate a table but without the int of 4 digits, the insertion of the values aren't possible because sql-server says this

```
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg
> 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102,
> Level 15, State 1, Line 125 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level
> 15, State 1, Line 126 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15,
> State 1, Line 126 Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State
> 1, Line 123 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1,
> Line 124 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line
> 125 Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 125
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 123
> Incorrect syntax near '='. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 124
> Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

And a lot more but they all say almost the same, almost 115 times I think.

Comment: This requires Dynamic SQL. There are plenty of examples out there too. Also, remove MySQL tag, this totally looks like SQL Server.

Comment: Try to print out the whole statement. Should make it easy to spot the problem. Also, you may want to add some spaces. Finally, unless this is a student project, reconsider your approach. You should not be creating tables on the fly.

Comment: yep, it's a project for students I will try to copy the whole statement I think 115 are too much (sqlserver crashed right now for another reason)

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something? How about

```
select * into newtable from platos;
```

Or if your table creation is ok, and you have manually inserted your first rows, use an insert select:

```
insert into newtable (col1, col2, col3, col4) 
select cola, colb, colc, cold from oldtable;
```